# How to figure out why a SATA hard-drive wont show in /dev/ and (therefore) wont mount

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I had an external hard-drive which got messed up. I then opened it and plugged the SATA-Hard-Drive directly into my computer. But after boot it is just showing my IDE-Hard-Drive on which the OS is. No secondary is shown.

```
sudo blkid -o list -w /dev/null
device                                                                            fs_type         label            mount point                                                                           UUID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1                                                                                                  ntfs                  System-reserviert      /media/System-reserviert                                                                                       FAE80411E803CB39
/dev/sda2                                                                                                  ntfs                                         /media/4AF809FAF809E4D3                                                                                        4AF809FAF809E4D3
/dev/sda5                                                                                                  ext4                                         /                                                                                                              fb8c4c85-12dc-44ad-a1e3-3b9b0ceb278f
/dev/sda6                                                                                                  ext4                                         /home                                                                                                          7560f5da-cd21-4fca-9d87-b8921c058b87
/dev/sda7                                                                                                  swap                                         <swap>                                                                                                         e8a31868-91c2-4da5-8551-f7a9a8d4e536
```

-

```
fdisk -l
Platte /dev/sda: 203.9 GByte, 203927027200 Byte
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 24792 Zylinder
Einheiten = Zylinder von 16065 × 512 = 8225280 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa252a252

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 endet nicht an einer Zylindergrenze.
/dev/sda2              13        8414    67481600    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            8415       24793   131560449    5  Erweiterte
/dev/sda5            8415       13278    39061504   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           13278       24219    87889920   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           24220       24793     4606976   82  Linux Swap / Solaris
```

-

```
sudo lsusb
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 03f0:0805 Hewlett-Packard HP4470C
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:6204 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet 5150c
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I found some entries at the syslog which might be related:

```
[    0.771747] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xd800 ctl 0xdc00 bmdma 0xe800 irq 19
[    6.320028] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   10.820029] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   16.370030] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   20.390081] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   20.410139] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[   30.940029] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   35.440032] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   40.990028] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   44.230062] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   44.250138] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[   44.250143] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   54.780030] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   59.280027] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   64.830029] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   68.250061] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[   68.270137] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[   78.800049] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   83.300049] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   88.850030] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   91.670060] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
```

It is possible that not just the USB controller of the external shell got damaged, but also the drive itself.

But how do I make sure that the hard-drive is damaged, and therefore not showing itself in /dev?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l` too?

Comment: i edited in hope it helps

Comment: Probably also output of `lsusb` (is the enclosure shown at all?) and any `dmesg` that appears when you plug it in, could help.

Comment: i searched dmesg and added lsusb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see all resources and tricks known to me are exhausted, therefore I consider my drive to be dead.

I am going to ask a professional though, if any new data is available I will edit them in. But **currently "drive is dead" is the most fitting answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Big guess here:
Try to remove external drive and set it from Master to Slave.
Duh, my bad. Check in BIOS if this external drive is listed.

Comment: Sata master and slave? Sata?

Comment: already thought about it but SATA does not care about master slave and I got just one IDE drive

Comment: just one drive is show in the bios menue